# Best way to version an MBean?

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

Essentially, I require [this MBean](http://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12408456/BasicDataSourceMBean.patch) to be built and deployed to my tomcat servers. Ideally, this would just exist as an external library and dependency, but I've found no-such official distributed jar of such (perhaps due to the simplicity). The interface and implementation of this file is likely to never change, but I don't feel that including the source in my main java project root is the right way to go.

I could create an internally versioned project for this file which only creates the dependency jar, but is this proper? Would you just stick the source in your main code line, or would you create a separate project for a single source file?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The interface and implementation of this file is likely to never change, but I don't feel that including the source in my main java project root is the right way to go.

Well, I guess that the MBean is deployed to the same location than your project (or you wouldn't ask the question) so the real question actually is "if the interface changes, what do you want to redeliver?". If it's acceptable to redeliver the full project, then I wouldn't mind putting that class in the main tree. If not, then create a separate project.